# CefSharp SetZoomLevel not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.5, cefsharp

I am using in a WinForm an object of type:
`CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser`

Everything is working fine but I am having an issue when I try to change the ZoomLevel with `SetZoomLevel` method:

```
If oBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized Then
    oBrowser.SetZoomLevel(-2.0)
    Dim frame As CefSharp.IFrame = oBrowser.GetMainFrame
    Dim request As CefSharp.IRequest = frame.CreateRequest()

    request.Url = url
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.InitializePostData()
    Dim element = request.PostData.CreatePostDataElement()
    element.Bytes = postDataBytes
    request.PostData.AddElement(element)

    request.Headers = headers

    frame.LoadRequest(request)
End If
```

The first time I open the WinForm the Zoom level doesn't change, while it works correctly from the 2nd refresh.

Am I missing some initialization and/or method call... Or do I have to call this method in another position?

*Note: the CEFSharp DLL version is 63.0.3.0.
The .NET Framework is 4.5.2*

---

**EDITED 01.06.2018**: I've found a solution (see below) but now **there's another problem**: ***the zoom change is made when the browser is already visible***, so it's not nice for the final user to see the page size changing during the form load.

Has anyone a suggestion to freeze the layout during zoom change? Please note that `.SuspendLayout()` and `.ResumeLayout()` are not working.

Comment: When are you calling your code? It's possible you might need to execute it later. What happens if you change the zoom level after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to answer my own question. I post it here as it could be useful to other users.

You must add a `LoadingStateChanged` handler to the `ChromiumWebBrowser` object:

```
AddHandler oBrowser.LoadingStateChanged, AddressOf WebBrowserOnLoadingStateChanged
```

The method would be then something like:

```
Private Sub WebBrowserOnLoadingStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal loadingStateChangedEventArgs As LoadingStateChangedEventArgs)
    Dim oBrowser As WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser = CType(sender, WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser)

    If Not oBrowser.IsLoading Then
        oBrowser.SetZoomLevel(-2.0)
    End If
End Sub
```

This solution works good in my environment but now **there's another problem**: the zoom change is made when the browser is already visible, so it's not nice for the final user to see the Zoom Level changing during the form load.